# Create source representation instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I followed the documentation to create an external replica of cloud SQL [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-replica). I have a MySQL   instance with version 8.0 on Google cloud. I successfully created the external read replica. Now, I want to demote this replica to master. I need to create a source representation instance for that. I called the following API as mentioned in the documentation.

```
gcloud auth login
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{
         "name": "[SOURCE_REPRESENTATION_NAME]",
         "region": "[REGION]",
         "databaseVersion": "[EXTERNAL_SERVER_MYSQL_VERSION]",
         "onPremisesConfiguration": {
             "hostPort": "[EXTERNAL_SERVER_IP]:[EXTERNAL_SERVER_PORT]"
         }
     }' \
     -X POST \
     https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances
```

The API works when I set databaseVersion to 5. But it fails when I try to set to version 8.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Missing parameter: DatabaseVersion.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Missing parameter: DatabaseVersion.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is the MySQL version 8 not supported for representational server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external#create-source-request):

`databaseVersion` should be *the MySQL version running on your source database server. The choices are MYSQL_5_5, MYSQL_5_6, MYSQL_5_7 or MYSQL_8_0.*